# Local Storage and Storing arrays into a local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, wordpress

I am building a RAL color selector and want the data stored in local storage to use on a different page of the website. I've been trying a lot of different ways to store the JSON inside localStorage but can't seem to get it working.

The script broke when I had it working for a moment. What am I doing wrong? It seems the `i` variable does not get included into the `kleuren` array.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  kleuren = [];
  
  jQuery(".kleur-box").on({
    mouseenter: function(event) {
      jQuery(this).addClass("block");
    },
    mouseleave: function(event) {
      jQuery(this).removeClass("block");
    },
    click: function(event) {
      kleuren = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("kleuren"));
      var i = jQuery(this).find('h4').text();
      alert(i);
      //Kijk of i in kleuren array zit anders remove

      var foundPresent = kleuren.includes(i);
      if (foundPresent === true) {
        kleuren = kleuren.filter(function(e) {
          return e !== i
        })
        localStorage.setItem("kleuren", JSON.stringify(kleuren));
        jQuery(this).removeClass("block_perma");

      } else {
        kleuren.push(i); //Add the text 'item1' to nameArr
        localStorage.setItem("kleuren", JSON.stringify(kleuren));
        jQuery(this).addClass("block_perma");

      }
      alert(localStorage.getItem("kleuren"));
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This is almost impossible to debug accurately without a working example including all the HTML, however you should at least provide a default value for `kleuren` if localStorage is undefined, which it will be on first visit: `kleuren = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("kleuren") || '[]');`. Also, check the console for errors. That will give you a message you can research and debug too

Comment: Yes I do check the console but it gave me the null object error, which means I guess that the object has not been specified if I am right? Your solutions solved my problem so thanks for the help!